# select box : display text 'error' if value not exist in array

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I have a key value pair defined as below, which is being used for select using ng-options

```
 $scope.BucketEnum = [
    { display: 'Error', value: 0 },
    { display: '1', value: 1 },
    { display: '2', value: 2 },
    { display: '3', value: 3 },
    { display: '4', value: 4 },
    { display: '5', value: 5 },
    { display: 'Flows', value: 125 },
    { display: 'Recovery', value: 151 }
];
```

I am using this key value pair to display select box in ng-options

```
     <select ng-model="selectedBucket" ng-options="row.value as rows.display for row in BucketEnum" multiple="multiple" ></select>
```

now if I set ng-model i.e. `$scope.selectedBucket = 10`, I want to display the text Error. Is it possible to show value `Error` for all the values which are not there in `$scope.BucketEnum` array.

**NOTE**

I am looking at a more generic way to do this e.g a filter for doing this

**SCENARIO**

There is certain historical data in database, which has some garbage and some good data.

For each garbage value, i need to show the current garbage value as well as the valid values to select from, so for the end users to fix it.

Comment: I think you can't do that with a $filter, a filter is just to filter the data with some process or conditions and return data to replace the original.. so I think you should implement a directive to fit your needs.

Comment: filter does receive the list of objects, so it should be possible

Comment: actually you cant use the filter for ng-repeat and also you cant use a filter for an ng-model assigment, so the only way I imagine is calling the filter in the scope, see my answer.. hope will useful.. Edit: I guess this would be only for setting the initials values, right?

Comment: What do you mean with error values can come randomly ?

Comment: So if your initials are 1,2,5,10,12 you need to append 10 and 12 with error as 'display' in your select ?

Comment: i would rather say.. if value of bucket field for the current row in table is not in 1,2,5 then add it to list with display as Error

Comment: I guess this will only when setting the initials values right ? if that is the case, maybe this would work for you http://jsfiddle.net/rahpuser/vzsahavn/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this fit your needs ?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rahpuser/vzsahavn/)

```
app.filter('bootstrapValues', function(){
    return function(initial, baseBucket){
        var result = [];
        for(var i=0; i<initial.length; i++){
            var flag = false;
            for(var j=1; j<baseBucket.length; j++){ //from 1 or 0.. you call
                if(initial[i] === baseBucket[j].value){
                    flag = true;
                    result.push(baseBucket[j]);
                    break; // if there are repeated elements
                }
            }
            if(!flag)
                result.push(baseBucket[0])
        }
        return result;
    };
});
```

Using it to start the selectedBucket, in your controller:

```
   // setting initials
        $scope.selectedBucket = $filter('bootstrapValues')(initialSet, $scope.bucketEnum);
```

Does it help?

Edit: Here is other [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vzsahavn/2/) with little modifications, if the value is not in the bucket it add the element to the list with Error display and as a selected value.

Comment: the updated fiddle did the job.. exactly what i was looking for. though needs little modification given that the error values come as part of api response, so i dont have the error list with me from start...

Answer (score 2):

Using ng-options generates multiple HTML `<select>` elements for each item in your `BucketEnum` array and 'returns' the selected value in your ng-model variable: `selectedBucket`. I think the only way to display the options without an additional blank entry is to ensure the value of `selectedBucket` is a valid entry in `BucketEnum`.

Your question states:

> if I set ng-model i.e. `$scope.selectedBucket = 10`, I want to display
>   the text Error.

I assume you want to display the value: `{{BucketEnum[selectedBucket].display}}`

So... starting with `$scope.selectedBucket = 10`, we want some generic way of implementing a select using ng-options which will reset this value to a default.

You could do this by implementing an attribute directive, allowing you to write:

```
<select ng-model="selectedBucket" select-default="BucketEnum"
        ng-options="row.value as row.display for row in BucketEnum" 
        multiple="multiple">
```

An example of this approach is shown below. Note that this assumes the default value is zero and does not handle multiple selections (you'd have to iterate over the selections when comparing to each item in BucketEnum and decide what to do if there is a mix of valid and invalid selections).

```
app.directive("selectDefault",function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        link:function(scope,element,attrs){
            var arr= scope[attrs.selectDefault];    // array from attribute  
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel,function(){
                var i, ok=false;
                var sel= scope[attrs.ngModel];      // ng-model variable
                for( i=0; i<arr.length; i++){       // variable in array ?
                    if( arr[i].value == sel )       // nasty '==' only for  demo
                        ok= true;
                }
                if( ! ok )
                    scope[attrs.ngModel]=0;    // set selectedBucket to 0
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I've run up a [jsfiddle of this here](http://jsfiddle.net/tonywilk/h9b9zf4r/1/)

The downside of this is that I've used a $watch on the ng-model which causes side-effects, i.e. any assignment of the named variable will trigger the $watch function.

If this is the sort of solution you were looking for, you could expand the directive in all sorts of ways, for example:

```
<select ng-model="selectResult"
        select-default="99" array="BucketEnum" initial="selectedBucket"
        ng-options="row.value as row.display for row in BucketEnum" 
        multiple="multiple">
```

...the idea being that the `select-default` directive would read the default value ("99" here), the `array` and an `initial` value then set `selectResult` accordingly

Comment: I tested it with this:     $timeout(function(){
    
  $scope.selectedBucket = 10;       // start with invalid bucket
        console.log("value 10")
    }, 5000);
its working great

Answer (score 1):

You would need to code for this explicitly.  Scan the choices you want to set against the choices that are present. If you don't find it, select the Error value too.

Note also that you need to pass an array for selectedBucket and it needs to include the actual option objects not just the values inside them.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <p>Select something</p>
    <select ng-model="selectedBucket" 
     ng-options="row as row.display for row in bucketEnum" multiple="multiple">
    </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {

     var initialSet = [1, 5, 10];

     $scope.bucketEnum = [
        { display: 'Error', value: 0 },
        { display: '1', value: 1 },
        { display: '2', value: 2 },
        { display: '3', value: 3 },
        { display: '4', value: 4 },
        { display: '5', value: 5 },
        { display: 'Flows', value: 125 },
        { display: 'Recovery', value: 151 }
     ];

    var selected = [];
    var error = $scope.bucketEnum[0];
    angular.forEach(initialSet, function(item) {
        var found;
        angular.forEach($scope.bucketEnum, function (e) {
            if (+item == +e.value) {
                console.log('Found ', e);
              found = item;
              selected.push(e);
            }
        });
        if (typeof found === 'undefined') {
            selected.push(error);
        }
        $scope.selectedBucket = selected;
        console.log(selected);
      });
 });
```

Comment: can I somehow not push this in filter or something, to make it generic... I was looking at more generic solution, else its simply matter of doing the lookup and set to error if not found...

Comment: You *could* write an angular filter to filter the `bucketEnum` to retrieve just the ones that match `initialSet` but you'd still need to add on the error one afterwards. You could do that by comparing the length of the filtered list to the length of the initialSet, if they aren't equal some element didn't match but you can't do it inside the loop. But it doesn't sound any simpler / easier to read than the code above.

Comment: You could also move this code to a directive or a service to make it more reuseable and to keep your controller 'skinny'.